# A grammar for one variable functions in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

Hey!
I am looking for an ANTLR grammar for parsing one variable function expressions. It should support +,-, /, ^, special functions (e.g. cos, sin) and constants (pi, e) and parenthesis. I tried writing it myself but I get left-recursion warnings. Does anyone have a example that I can get started with?
I would like to write something like

```
x+sin(5x + pi^3)/(15e cos(x))
```

for example.
ANTLR grammars are preferred but other (E)BNF examples will be appreciated.

Eventually I would like to use it with AST output.

THANX

Comment: What does your attempt look like so far?

Comment: Any reason why you don't have an explicit operator for multiply? This will make it harder to write a grammar and parser

Comment: @peter.murray.rust it is not a must, it can be nice to support it.

Comment: The example you have found looks a good way of getting started with ANTLR. It *does* have an explicit multiply operator and I strongly suggest you adopt this convention. "Invisible times" is usually a lot harder to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was fast.
I found a [great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx) on code project.

It has everything I wanted and more!